# Shiny + DT: Single Cell Selection

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to use the development version of the DT package (available at `devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')`) to enable single cell selection in a shiny application.  I have been able to make the selection be cells using the `target` argument for `selection`; however, I can't figure out how to disable multiple cells being selected.  Is there another argument for the `selection` parameter list that will allow me to restrict the user's selection to a max of 1 cell?  If not, is there another way to accomplish single cell selection?

I am very open to revert back to the stable version of `DT` on CRAN if there is an easier solution using that version of the package.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data("mtcars")

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("myDatatable"),
    verbatimTextOutput("selectedCells")
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$myDatatable <- DT::renderDataTable(mtcars, 
                                            selection=list(target="cell"),
                                            server = FALSE,
                                            rownames=FALSE)

  output$selectedCells <- renderPrint(input$myDatatable_cells_selected)
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is in your call to `DT::renderDataTable` in the `selection` list.  You need `selection=list(mode="single", target="cell")`

`mode` sets single or multiple where you had `selection` (before your edit)

Comment: Is there also a mode that only allows one selection per row?

Comment: @JdP Do you mean pick one whole row or one cell within a row?

Comment: I meant one cell within a row, so for each row one option to select

Comment: I'm still trying to find this - one cell per row only - but very difficult to find